# Hard 'sketch and toon style' shadows in Eevee?

Tags: eevee-render-engine

I'm quite new to Blender, but I created this little illustration based off Brian Michael Gossett's work to practice my skills. Quite happy with the progress, but the problem is that the shadows are actually fake. They're just black meshes positioned right below every single object to make it look real. I was wondering if it's possible to actually create real hard shadows in Eevee as such, so that I can also animate this illustration. Does anyone know? If so, how?

[image]

Comment: nice artwork :)

Answer (score 1):

In EEVEE, you can toonify as much as you like by using the Shader to RGB node, and passing the resulting color through a threshold:

[image]

Here, the floor-plane receiving the shadow has the material shown... original shadows, in this case, soft, and hardened in the color ramp.

The background curve is just the natural fade of a Sun lamp by reflected angle, caught at a certain level of grey by the threshold.

Answer (score 0):

Great work, especially given the shadows made by hand!!

The maximum hard shadows in eevee I've got by using VSM Shadows Method, High Bitdepth and higher maps size that default with Shadow+Contact Softness to 0.000

[image: hard shadows]

Comment: Ah, thank you! I'm guessing the shadows will be even darker if I make the world's background color pitch black, right? Your methods works quite well, though. The challenge for me now is to try to position the shadows directly beneath every single object... not as easy, but I guess I just have to experiment with the positioning of the sun light. Thanks again!